# Ajax .done() and .fail() firing simultaneously

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-confirm

I'm using [Jquery Confirm](http://craftpip.github.io/jquery-confirm/) when I trigger my ajax call I get a status response of 200 but my .done() and .fail() are firing simultaneously. Am I correct that .done() will fire if response received is 200?

```
var frameid = $('#frameID').val();

$('.change-frame').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.confirm({
        title: 'Changing your Base frame?',
        content: 'Let us know what happened to it.<br><span>This will also delete your frame in our database</span>.',
        animation: 'scale',
        closeAnimation: 'scale',
        draggable: false,
        buttons: {
            'Sold': {
                text: 'I sold it',
                btnClass: 'btn-dark',
                action: function () {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: '/base-frame/delete',
                        data: {frameid},
                        dataType: 'json',
                    }).done(function(){
                        console.log('SUCCESS')
                    }).fail(function(){
                        console.log('FAILED')
                    });

                }
            },
            'Traded': {
                text: 'I traded it',
                btnClass: 'btn-dark',
                action: function () {
                    $.alert('You Traded your Frame');
                }
            },
            Stolen: {
                text: 'It was stolen',
                btnClass: 'btn-dark',
                action: function () {
                    $.alert('Sorry to hear that');
                }
            },
        }
    });
});
```

What am I doing wrong here?

**UPDATE**

Tried to force the response to 400 but still .done() and .fail() are firing simultaneously

Comment: Use `success` handler instead.

Comment: Which jQuery Version are you using?

Comment: using version 3.2.1